# Getting a base value into ValueTransformer

Tags: swift

I'm trying to output a value relative to a base value that is calculated elsewhere. I was hoping that ValueTransformer would do the trick but I have no idea how to get a base value into the ValueTransformer.The initWithBase func shown below does not work. Any advice would be welcome. Thanks.

```
import Cocoa

class PercentTransformer: ValueTransformer {
    var baseValue: Double = 1
    override class func transformedValueClass() -> Swift.AnyClass {
        return NSString.self
    }

    override class func allowsReverseTransformation() -> Bool {
        return false
    }

    func initWithBase(base: Double) {
        baseValue = base
        return
    }

    override func transformedValue(_ value: Any?) -> Any? {
        let inputValue = value as! Double
        if inputValue == 0.0 {
            return "--------------"
        }
        // calculate output value
        let percent = inputValue/baseValue * 100
        let output = String(format: "%.2e", inputValue) + "  " + String(format: "%.1f", percent) + "%"
        return output as NSString
    }
}
```